# Problem deploying my dashboard on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, database, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I made a dataviz on r shiny but when I want to deploy with shinyapp.io I get errors (I think it's because my database is local on my RStudio).
But I don't know how to do this.

Thank you in advance for your answer
Good day to you

I created an account shinyapps.io and I carried out the deployment but I had an error directly:

Error in eval(exprs, envir) : object 'baseVehicule' not found

Comment: How do expect your remote app to access your local database?

Comment: That's where the problem lies, because I don't know how to get them to access my databases.

Comment: If you need your users to have access to each other's data or if you want an individual user's data to persist between sessions, you'll need a third-party solution such as AWS: shinyapps.io doesn't host databases.  If each user needs access only to their data and only for a single session, you may be able to get away with storing initial data in the app or allowing users to upload data.  But I feel that, as it stands, your question is missing so much essential information that it is impossible to answer.